# Run a clock or timer even when app is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I would like to know how to run a clock or timer that works even the app is closed.
I have this code in my `ViewDidLoad`:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *time = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

This code only works when the user open up the view. But I want to know how to create a clock that works all the time even when the phone is locked. I just need some guide.
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. 1) register your app as one of the Apple approved [background apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24), of which simple timer apps are not, and 2) set a [local notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) using your time.